# Gooey эффект не работает с canvas

Tags: javascript, svg, canvas

Пробовала на дивах, там эффект срабатывает, а на канвасе нет. Не понимаю что я упустила.

[Демкa](https://codepen.io/Vladasha/pen/poEpMpM)

```
 <svg>
        <defs>
            <filter id="goo">
                <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="20" result="blur" />
                <feColorMatrix in="blur" type="matrix" 
                   values=" 1 0 0 0 0
                            0 1 0 0 0
                            0 0 1 0 0
                            0 0 0 22 -9" />
                <feBlend in="SourceGraphic" in2="blur" ></feBlend>
            </filter>
        </defs>
    </svg>
```

```
(() => {
   const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
   const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
   let w = canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
   let h = canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

   ctx.textBaseline = 'middle';
   let lettersArray = ['H', 'E', 'L', 'L', 'O'];
   let hue = 0;
   const particles = [];
   let numberOfParticles = (w * h) / 100;
   let numberOfParticlesStop = numberOfParticles / 50;

   const mouse = {
      x: 0,
      y: 0,
      radius: 20,
      autopilotAngle: 0
   }
   window.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => {
      mouse.x = e.x;
      mouse.y = e.y;
   })

   class Particle {
      constructor(x,y,radius) {
         this.x = x;
         this.y = y;
         this.radius = radius;
         this.color = `hsl(${hue}, 100%, 50%)`;
         this.text = lettersArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * lettersArray.length)];
      }
      draw() {
         ctx.beginPath();
         ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, this.radius, 0, Math.PI * 2);
         ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
         ctx.closePath();
         ctx.fill();

         ctx.beginPath();
         ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, this.radius * .85, 0, Math.PI * 1.5, true);
         ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
         ctx.fill();

         ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
         ctx.font = `700  ${this.radius}px  sans-serif`;
         ctx.fillText(this.text, this.x - this.radius / 2.6, this.y);
      }

      update() {
         if(mouse.x === undefined && mouse.y === undefined) {
            let newX = mouse.radius * w / 50 * Math.sin(mouse.autopilotAngle * (Math.PI / 50))
            let newY = mouse.radius * h / 50 * Math.cos(mouse.autopilotAngle * (Math.PI / 60))

            mouse.x = newX + w/2;
            mouse.y = newY + h/2;
         }
         mouse.autopilotAngle += 0.01;
      }
   }

   function handleOverlap() {
      let overlapping = false;
      let protection = 300;
      let counter = 0;

      while (particles.length < numberOfParticles &&
         counter < protection) {
         let randomAngle = Math.random() * 2 * Math.PI;
         let randomRadius = mouse.radius * Math.sqrt(Math.random()) * 4;
         let particle = {
            x: mouse.x + randomRadius * Math.cos(randomAngle),
            y: mouse.y + randomRadius * Math.sin(randomAngle),
            radius: Math.floor(Math.random() * mouse.radius) + 10
         }
         let overlapping = false;

         for(let i = 0; i < particles.length; i++) {
            let previousParticle = particles[i];
            let distance = Math.hypot(particle.x - previousParticle.x, particle.y - previousParticle.y)
            if (distance < (particle.radius + previousParticle.radius)) {
               overlapping = true;
               break;
            }
         }

         if(!overlapping) {
            particles.unshift(new Particle(particle.x, particle.y, particle.radius))
         }
         counter++;
      }

   }
   handleOverlap();

   function animate() {
      ctx.clearRect(0,0,w,h);

      for(let i = 0; i < particles.length; i++) {
         particles[i].draw();
         particles[i].update();
      }

      if(particles.length >= numberOfParticlesStop) {
         for (let i=0; i < numberOfParticlesStop / 20; i++) {
            particles.pop();
         }
      }

      handleOverlap();
      hue++;
      requestAnimationFrame(animate)
   }
   animate();

   let autopilot = setInterval(() => {
      mouse.x = undefined
      mouse.y = undefined
   }, 40)

   canvas.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
      autopilot = setInterval(() => {
         mouse.x = undefined
         mouse.y = undefined
      }, 40)
   })

   canvas.addEventListener('mouseenter', () => {
      clearInterval(autopilot)
      autopilot = undefined;
   })

})()
```

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

canvas {
  background: #ffffff;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  z-index: 1;
  filter:url('#goo');
}
```

Comment: `ctx.filter = "url(#goo)";` только комп начинает тупить, скорее всего надо применять requestAnimationFrame

Comment: @MaximLensky не сработало :(

Comment: у меня то сработало - только тормозит - очень сильно ...наверно надо делать по другому

Comment: Спасибо, что посмотрели

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**РЕШЕНО.**
Нашла в чём дело. Не надо фон задавать в canvas потому что. Удаляем из css

```
canvas {background: #fffff;}
```